# Cloud storage API

Tags: cloud

Is there any cloud storage (Dropbox, Google Drive) which I can easily use (via API) to upload files generated in a batch processing script?

I will require an API which I can use in my other program code to access the cloud storage.

Any advise would be valuable to me.

Comment: [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/apis). [NextCloud](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/15/developer_manual/client_apis/index.html) and a few others have solutions. Solutions with [OneDrive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onedrive-concept-overview) are also available, but less robust IMO.

Comment: If you have to transfer a lot of files on a daily basis, a lot of edge-cases will eventually appear. So I would recommend to have a close look at the documentation that the cloud vendor provides. It should have many, rich code examples (in your favourite language) that you can adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Backblaze do a storage solution called B2 which might suit. I haven't looked at it since the early betas, so I'm well behind the times on it - see
https://www.backblaze.com/b2/cloud-storage.html

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a look into this.